# Twilio bulk message

Tags: twilio

When I use Node.js to send bulk message to Twilio.I can not receive message,and I got some error in console log.The error is Error 52001.
My code is:

```
const body = 'test for send message';
const numbers = ['+861663610424239', '+8618015581301802', 
'+86158266342'];
const service = twilio.notify.services(notifyServerId);
const bindings = numbers.map((number) => {
return JSON.stringify({ binding_type: 'sms', address: number });
});

console.log('bindings: ', bindings);
const notification = service.notifications
    .create({
      toBinding: bindings,
      body: body,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('[notifications]: ', notification);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('[notifications]: error: ', err);
    });
```

Error message text:

```
bindingType | "sms"
module | "SMS_BA"
description | "Invalid sms binding with address '+861663610424239' sid 
'null': Address of sms binding must be a valid phone number"
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As the error says, "+861663610424239" isn't a valid phone number.

As far as I can see you are trying to send to a Chinese mobile phone number. From what I can [read about them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_China#Mobile_phones), Chinese mobile numbers are in the format +86 (country) 166 (operator) xxxx-xxxx (8 further digits). That number is 2 digits too long.

The other numbers you are using seem to be too long or too short too. If these are real numbers then I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and explain your issue.